# How to redirect the page?

Tags: php, jquery

My URL: `timeline.php?id=SSM_offline128&message=SUCCESS`

```
<?php
    $ssmid=$_GET['id'];
    $message=$_GET['message'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var message = '<?php echo $message; ?>';
    if(message == 'SUCCESS'){
        $('#success_message').show();   
    }
</script>
```

My code is working fine, but some directly come to this url means I want redirect to `timeline.php?id=SSM_offline128`

Comment: why don't you check the values of your GET variables and have the page render accordingly if they are `undefined`?

Comment: What is the desired functionality? Do you want the user to read the success message for a split second then have the page redirect via JavaScript? Or do you want to redirect first then display the success message on the next page?

Comment: I think you should use session/cookie to store and display your message instead of adding it in query string

Comment: do you want this to happen every time they come from outside on this link or is there some special case when this should happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
header('Location:timeline.php');
}
```

but its not recommended that to use $_GET because any one can set that in url and access it you must use $_POST for security purpose.